# Any better and robust way for waiting for element in Selenium WedDriver C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I use following code to wait for element in my test scripts. Is there any better and robust way to wait for an element?

```cs
try {
    isPresent = localWait.Until<bool>((d) => { 
        return element.Size.Height > 0 && element.Size.Width > 0; });
} catch (NoSuchElementException) {
    isPresent = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The predicate `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible` waits for an element to be displayed and for a width/height superior to zero:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector(...)));
```

It's also possible to wait for the `Displayed` property:

```
wait.Until(drv => element.Displayed);
```

Comment: The reason I don't use `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By locator)`  is it doesn't accept `WebElement` in C#. It accepts `By locator`. And are you sure 'Displayed' is as robust as `element.Size.Height > 0 && element.Size.Width > 0` ?

Comment: Do you have a specific case where it doesn't behave as expected? See the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-displayedness